# How to make page load time faster?

Tags: javascript, performance, deployment, frontend, reveal.js

I have created an web app. In a page I've used reveal.js presentation framework. It has 44 slides (sections). In each slides there are two audio .mp3 files and three global audio .mp3 background music. Also there are 15-20 .png images. In total all audios are 53 mb and all images are 10 mb. All slides and audios will be played automatically.

In local server there is no problem with page loading. But when I deployed it to heroku it's taking huge time. Then I enabled lazy loading for media by changing src to data-src. Now page loads within some seconds but maximum audios are not playing fully. What should I do now?

Just to let you know. This web app might have huge users. and each user can browse this page only once, so unfortunately no caching.

Is there any way to solve this problem? How to make page load faster? without breaking the images and audios auto-playing? Which type of server should I use?

Answer (score 0):

Decrease the quality of the audio and images